# Array to Lower Case

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hello everyone I have a problem with my Java programm. I want to convert my Array into a LowerCase Array.

```
public class Main {


    public static char[] bubblesort(char[] plain) {
        int temp;
        for(int i=1; i<plain.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<plain.length-i; j++) {
                if(plain[j]>plain[j+1]) {
                    temp=plain[j];
                    plain[j]=plain[j+1];
                    plain[j+1]=(char) temp;
                }

            }
        }
        return plain;
    }

    public static char [] ArrayToLowerCase(char [] plain ) {

        for (int i = 0; i < plain.length; i++) {

            plain[i] = plain[i].toLowerCase();

        }
        return plain;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        String plaintext = "Test";

        char[] plain = plaintext.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(bubblesort(plain));
      //   System.out.println(s.toLowerCase());     
    }
```

I want to have my Array plain into only Lower Case. What did I wrong in my ArrayToLowerCase Method?

Comment: What is the question all about?

Comment: You never call `ArrayToLowerCase` in your code...

Comment: You have a basic misunderstanding here. An Array is a collection of things. You can only "lowercase" a string. There's no such thing as a "lowercase array". I suspect you mean you have an array of characters that you want to convert into an array of lowercase characters. Your example doesn't do that either.
You're also not calling "ArrayToLowerCase".

Answer (score 0):

```
        plain[i] = Character.toLowerCase(plain[i]);
```

Try this and it will work. Also you are not calling the ArrayToLowerCase method anywhere.

```
    System.out.println(bubblesort(ArrayToLowerCase(plain)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to convert your chars arrays to a `toLowerCase` you can make it like this :

```
public static char[] ArrayToLowerCase(char[] plain) {
    return String.copyValueOf(plain).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
}
```

or if you want better way, you don't need to convert your String to array to use LowerCase you can just use :

```
String plaintext = "Test";
plaintext = plaintext.toLowerCase();
```